# ag-grid: how to get or save the sorted state from grid column

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid ("^13.3.1") and Angular 4, would like to save or get the sorted column state If the page is refreshed, I am getting error while using sortModel "Cannot read property 'getSortModel' of undefined", Please anyone can help through.

grid.component.ts

```
saveSort() {
    this.savedSort = this.gridOptions.api.getSortModel();
    console.log("Saved sort: " + JSON.stringify(this.savedSort));
  }
restoreFromSave() {
    this.gridOptions.api.setSortModel(this.savedSort);
  }
ngOnInit() {
    this.saveSort();
    this.restoreFromSave();
}
```

Comment: you are calling saveSort() in  ngOnInit and it seems you grid is not initialised yet.

Comment: I need to restore the state of sorted column, If the page is reloaded, So calling in ngOnInit. Even though tried to call a methods after initialization of grid, but no luck, got same error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSortModel' of undefined "

Answer (score 0):

as Fahim said you should do this after the grid is initialized:

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.restoreFromSave();
}
```